# MD5 Implementation in C++ is returning incorrect digest

Tags: c++, md5

I've recently been attempting to recreate the MD5 algorithm in C++ in order to implement it, later, as part of a CUDA project for a class. I've read over various resources, including [RFC1321](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt), various example implementations ([CUDA project #1](http://macs-site.net/md5oncudawhitepaper.html), [CUDA project #2](https://github.com/xpn/CUDA-MD5-Crack/blob/master/md5.cu), [C implementation gist](https://gist.github.com/creationix/4710780)), [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479760/implementation-of-md5-in-c) here on SO on the same topic.

My code currently is the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

#define MD5_INPUT_LENGTH 64

// Unsigned character - 8 bits
typedef unsigned char uchar_8;

// Unsigned int - 32 bits
typedef unsigned int uint_32;

// Unsigned long - 64 bit (for lengths)
typedef unsigned long uint_64;

static const uint_32 T[64] = {
  0xd76aa478, 0xe8c7b756, 0x242070db, 0xc1bdceee,
  0xf57c0faf, 0x4787c62a, 0xa8304613, 0xfd469501,
  0x698098d8, 0x8b44f7af, 0xffff5bb1, 0x895cd7be,
  0x6b901122, 0xfd987193, 0xa679438e, 0x49b40821,
  0xf61e2562, 0xc040b340, 0x265e5a51, 0xe9b6c7aa,
  0xd62f105d, 0x02441453, 0xd8a1e681, 0xe7d3fbc8,
  0x21e1cde6, 0xc33707d6, 0xf4d50d87, 0x455a14ed,
  0xa9e3e905, 0xfcefa3f8, 0x676f02d9, 0x8d2a4c8a,
  0xfffa3942, 0x8771f681, 0x6d9d6122, 0xfde5380c,
  0xa4beea44, 0x4bdecfa9, 0xf6bb4b60, 0xbebfbc70,
  0x289b7ec6, 0xeaa127fa, 0xd4ef3085, 0x04881d05,
  0xd9d4d039, 0xe6db99e5, 0x1fa27cf8, 0xc4ac5665,
  0xf4292244, 0x432aff97, 0xab9423a7, 0xfc93a039,
  0x655b59c3, 0x8f0ccc92, 0xffeff47d, 0x85845dd1,
  0x6fa87e4f, 0xfe2ce6e0, 0xa3014314, 0x4e0811a1,
  0xf7537e82, 0xbd3af235, 0x2ad7d2bb, 0xeb86d391
};

// Magic values for initialization
static const uint_32 A0 = 0x67452301;
static const uint_32 B0 = 0xefcdab89;
static const uint_32 C0 = 0x98badcfe;
static const uint_32 D0 = 0x10325476;

inline uint_32 F(uint_32 x, uint_32 y, uint_32 z) {
  return ((x & y) | (~x & z));
}

inline uint_32 G(uint_32 x, uint_32 y, uint_32 z) {
  return ((x & y) | (y & ~z));
}

inline uint_32 H(uint_32 x, uint_32 y, uint_32 z) {
  return (x ^ y ^ z);
}

inline uint_32 I(uint_32 x, uint_32 y, uint_32 z) {
  return (y ^ (x | ~z));
}

// Logical wrapping left shift handling
inline uint_32 shift(uint_32 x, uint_32 s) {
  return ((x << s) | (x >> (32 - s)));
}

// Round 1 handler
inline void FF(uint_32 &a, uint_32 b, uint_32 c, uint_32 d, uint_32 x, uint_32 s, uint_32 t) {
  a += F(b, c, d) + x + t;
  a = shift(a, s) + b;
}

// Round 2 handler
inline void GG(uint_32 &a, uint_32 b, uint_32 c, uint_32 d, uint_32 x, uint_32 s, uint_32 t) {
  a += G(b, c, d) + x + t;
  a = shift(a, s) + b;
}

// Round 3 handler
inline void HH(uint_32 &a, uint_32 b, uint_32 c, uint_32 d, uint_32 x, uint_32 s, uint_32 t) {
  a += H(b, c, d) + x + t;
  a = shift(a, s) + b;
}

// Round 4 handler
inline void II(uint_32 &a, uint_32 b, uint_32 c, uint_32 d, uint_32 x, uint_32 s, uint_32 t) {
  a += I(b, c, d) + x + t;
  a = shift(a, s) + b;
}

uint_32 *md5Pad(char *charBuf, uint_64 len) {
  // Number of characters in buffer * 8 mod 64
  uint_64 newLen;
  for (newLen = len * 8 + 1; newLen % 512 != 448; newLen++);
  newLen /= 8;

  // Initialize result buffer with null characters
  uint_32 *buf = new uint_32[newLen + 64];
  memset(buf, 0, newLen + 64);

  // Copy bytes from characters into uint memory space, no conversion necessary
  memcpy(buf, charBuf, len);

  // Append terminating char
  buf[len] = 0x80;

  // Append length to buffer
  uint_32 bitsLen = len * 8;
  memcpy(buf + newLen, &bitsLen, 4);

  return buf;
}

void MD5(uint_32 *outBuf, uint_32 *inBuf) {
  uint_32 a, b, c, d;

  const uint_32 a0 = 0x67452301;
  const uint_32 b0 = 0xEFCDAB89;
  const uint_32 c0 = 0x98BADCFE;
  const uint_32 d0 = 0x10325476;

  a = a0;
  b = b0;
  c = c0;
  d = d0;

  // Shift amounts 1st round
  static const uchar_8 S11 =  7;
  static const uchar_8 S12 = 12;
  static const uchar_8 S13 = 17;
  static const uchar_8 S14 = 22;

  FF ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[ 0], S11, T[ 0]); /* 1 */
  FF ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[ 1], S12, T[ 1]); /* 2 */
  FF ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[ 2], S13, T[ 2]); /* 3 */
  FF ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[ 3], S14, T[ 3]); /* 4 */

  FF ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[ 4], S11, T[ 4]); /* 5 */
  FF ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[ 5], S12, T[ 5]); /* 6 */
  FF ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[ 6], S13, T[ 6]); /* 7 */
  FF ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[ 7], S14, T[ 7]); /* 8 */

  FF ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[ 8], S11, T[ 8]); /* 9 */
  FF ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[ 9], S12, T[ 9]); /* 10 */
  FF ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[10], S13, T[10]); /* 11 */
  FF ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[11], S14, T[1]); /* 12 */ 

  FF ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[12], S11, T[12]); /* 13 */
  FF ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[13], S12, T[13]); /* 14 */
  FF ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[14], S13, T[14]); /* 15 */
  FF ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[15], S14, T[15]); /* 16 */

  // Shift amounts 2nd round
  static const uchar_8 S21 =  5;
  static const uchar_8 S22 =  9;
  static const uchar_8 S23 = 14;
  static const uchar_8 S24 = 20;

  GG ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[ 1], S21, T[16]); /* 17 */
  GG ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[ 6], S22, T[17]); /* 18 */
  GG ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[11], S23, T[18]); /* 19 */
  GG ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[ 0], S24, T[19]); /* 20 */

  GG ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[ 5], S21, T[20]); /* 21 */
  GG ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[10], S22, T[21]); /* 22 */
  GG ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[15], S23, T[22]); /* 23 */
  GG ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[ 4], S24, T[23]); /* 24 */

  GG ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[ 9], S21, T[24]); /* 25 */
  GG ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[14], S22, T[25]); /* 26 */
  GG ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[ 3], S23, T[26]); /* 27 */
  GG ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[ 8], S24, T[27]); /* 28 */

  GG ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[13], S21, T[28]); /* 29 */
  GG ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[ 2], S22, T[29]); /* 30 */
  GG ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[ 7], S23, T[30]); /* 31 */
  GG ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[12], S24, T[31]); /* 32 */

  // Shift amounts 3rd round
  static const uchar_8 S31 =  4;
  static const uchar_8 S32 = 11;
  static const uchar_8 S33 = 16;
  static const uchar_8 S34 = 23;

  HH ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[ 5], S31, T[32]); /* 33 */
  HH ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[ 8], S32, T[33]); /* 34 */
  HH ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[11], S33, T[34]); /* 35 */
  HH ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[14], S34, T[35]); /* 36 */

  HH ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[ 1], S31, T[36]); /* 37 */
  HH ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[ 4], S32, T[37]); /* 38 */
  HH ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[ 7], S33, T[38]); /* 39 */
  HH ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[10], S34, T[39]); /* 40 */

  HH ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[13], S31, T[40]); /* 41 */
  HH ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[ 0], S32, T[41]); /* 42 */
  HH ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[ 3], S33, T[42]); /* 43 */
  HH ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[ 6], S34, T[43]); /* 44 */

  HH ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[ 9], S31, T[44]); /* 45 */
  HH ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[12], S32, T[45]); /* 46 */
  HH ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[15], S33, T[46]); /* 47 */
  HH ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[ 2], S34, T[47]); /* 48 */

  // Shift amounts 4th round
  static const uchar_8 S41 =  6;
  static const uchar_8 S42 = 10;
  static const uchar_8 S43 = 15;
  static const uchar_8 S44 = 21;

  II ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[ 0], S41, T[48]); /* 49 */
  II ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[ 7], S42, T[49]); /* 50 */
  II ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[14], S43, T[50]); /* 51 */
  II ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[ 5], S44, T[51]); /* 52 */

  II ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[12], S41, T[52]); /* 53 */
  II ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[ 3], S42, T[53]); /* 54 */
  II ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[10], S43, T[54]); /* 55 */
  II ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[ 1], S44, T[55]); /* 56 */

  II ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[ 8], S41, T[56]); /* 57 */
  II ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[15], S42, T[57]); /* 58 */
  II ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[ 6], S43, T[58]); /* 59 */
  II ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[13], S44, T[59]); /* 60 */

  II ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[ 4], S41, T[60]); /* 61 */
  II ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[11], S42, T[61]); /* 62 */
  II ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[ 2], S43, T[62]); /* 63 */
  II ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[ 9], S44, T[63]); /* 64 */

  // Re-add initialization magic values
  a += a0;
  b += b0;
  c += c0;
  d += d0;

  outBuf[0] = a;
  outBuf[1] = b;
  outBuf[2] = c;
  outBuf[3] = d;

  return;
}

string intToHexReverseEndian(uint_32 val) {
  ostringstream ss;
  ss << hex << ((val >>  0) & 0xFF);
  ss << hex << ((val >>  8) & 0xFF);
  ss << hex << ((val >> 16) & 0xFF);
  ss << hex << ((val >> 24) & 0xFF);

  return ss.str();
}

int main() {
  char *srcStr = "";
  uint_32 *padded = md5Pad(srcStr, strlen(srcStr));

  uint_32 result[4] = {0};

  MD5(result, padded);
  uchar_8 digestChars[16] = {0};
  memcpy(digestChars, result, 16);

  cout << "Digest: " 
    << intToHexReverseEndian(result[0])
    << intToHexReverseEndian(result[1])
    << intToHexReverseEndian(result[2])
    << intToHexReverseEndian(result[3])
    << endl;

  delete[] padded;

  return 0;
}
```

I have been unable to get it to produce the correct hashes and I am unsure why, primarily because the implementations I have seen and attempted to work with have all varied in different ways.

Part of my problem may be due to some of mixing and matching of C and C++ code I've done in my various attempts, but I believe it has more to do with the way I'm copying the `char`/`unsigned int` values around, switching between them, and potentially the little endian format.

Currently the output I am getting is `Digest: 1aa849c0fde5f2bf548522832ab2d27`, which is not the correct hash for an empty string (`d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`). Does anyone know why, or where I should look to fix it?

Comment: Why not use the standard fixed width integer types from `<cstdint>` instead of inventing your own?

Comment: @Shawn I wasn't aware that was a thing. I primarily added those typedefs for my own clarity as I was working.

Comment: `typedef unsigned long uint_64;` Make sure that `unsigned long` is indeed a 64 bit type on your platform.

Comment: @RSahu I did, it's a 64 bit value based off `sizeof(unsigned long) * 8`

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness I would generally avoid `long`, its size varies between for example 32bit Windows/Linux (32bit long, 64 bit long long), 64bit Windows (32bit long, 64bit long long) and 64bit Linux (64bit for both). At least have some `static_assert`s to catch it if the code ever gets compiled/copied on another platform. Not to mention what more exotic platforms could validly choose to do.

Comment: `FF ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[11], S14, T[1]); /* 12 */` You have 1 here, it's probably should be 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you correct a couple of typos. First, in this part:

```
  FF ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[ 8], S11, T[ 8]); /* 9 */
  FF ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[ 9], S12, T[ 9]); /* 10 */
  FF ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[10], S13, T[10]); /* 11 */
  FF ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[11], S14, T[1]); /* 12 */   /*  <------- TYPO  */

  FF ( a, b, c, d, inBuf[12], S11, T[12]); /* 13 */
  FF ( d, a, b, c, inBuf[13], S12, T[13]); /* 14 */
  FF ( c, d, a, b, inBuf[14], S13, T[14]); /* 15 */
  FF ( b, c, d, a, inBuf[15], S14, T[15]); /* 16 */
```

You have `T[1]` where it should be `T[11]`.

Also, in the definition of the function G:

```
inline uint_32 G(uint_32 x, uint_32 y, uint_32 z) {
  return ((x & y) | (y & ~z));    /*  <------- TYPO  */
}
```

There you have `(x & y)` where it should be `(x & z)`.

After fixing those two issues, your code gives the d41d8cd98f0b24e980998ecf8427e as it should, matching the expected test suite result in https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt

Comment: I had actually figured that out on my own, but now I'm running into an issue with actually attempting to MD5 a string isn't giving the correct output. I'll be looking at figuring that out, but thank you for the answer!